# Windows didn't recognize my External HDD properly, should I replace it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

Some details:
External HDD: [WD Elements Portable 1TB](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B008GS8LT0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00)

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, SP1

The External HDD was working fine except sometimes when I eject it, windows says the device is in use. the device slowed down very badly, the transfer speed was about 4 MBPS(I usualy get about 25 MBPS), after reconnecting the device, therre was no problem.
after some days Windows didn't recognize my drive, it has 3 partition, of which only one shows up in Windows explorer, but I can't open that partition, opening it hangs explorer. (The command "list disk" in Diskpart didn't not complete, but if I disconnect the drive, the command completes.)
Another thing I noticed was that when I connect the HDD, my system seem to be slow.
Below is a SMART check result after formating the drive:
[image]

**UPDATE:** I ran WD Data LifeGuard Diagnostics and the test result is as given below, actually, it failed:
[image]

**Note: WD DLGDIAG could not repair the drive.**

Should I replace the drive as it failed the test?( I have 3 year warranty from WD)

To put my query simply, **Should I replace the drive?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes! Replace the drive.** It's failed multiple diagnostics, and you're noticing performance issues with it too. It's dying.

Comment: Yes, this is not good. Bad sectors mean that your drive is going downhill - things will stop working before too long. Make sure your data is stored elsewhere. Of course test using a different cable and port as Techpumpkin_WD suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of WD DLG error codes here http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=krjAIc.

If a WD HDD fails any of the WD DLG tests you should change the USB/SATA cable and port, reboot the system and repeat the test. If the test fails again you should replace the drive. Please contact our support team to start the RMA http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=vQ2iC6 .

Comment: retesting the drive is a time consuming work, it took about 10 hour for me to run an extended test, meanwhile I do not have a spare cable to test with.

Comment: 10 hours is too long for that capacity, but there is a chance that there is a problem with the SATA cable. You can try a different machine if possible, if not call the support team to start the RMA.